# Typescript Nested Object Structure Conditional/Recursion Type

Tags: typescript, recursion, types, interface, conditional-statements

I have the following type:

```
type Config = {
  key: string,
  label?: string,
  value?: any,
}
```

I want to be able to parse through a deeply nested object of these "Config's". Something like this:

```
  feature1: {
    field1: {
      key: `field1`,
    },
    field2: {
      key: `field2`,
    },
  },

  feature2: {
    group1: {
      field: {
        key: `group1_field`,
      },
    },
    group2: {
      field: {
        key: `group2_field`,
      },
    },
  },

  feature3: {
    group1: {
      subgroup1: {
        field: {
          key: `group1_subgroup1_field`,
        },
      },
      subgroup2: {
        field: {
          key: `group1_subgroup2_field`,
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

The config's can appear at any depth in the object.

How would I go about writing up a Typescript Type to handle this structure?

I've been playing around with this code thus far:

```
type Config = {
  key: string,
  label?: string,
  value?: any,
}

type ConfigMapping = {
  [key: string]: Config
}

export type NestedConfig<T> = T extends Config ? Config : {
  [K in keyof T]:
  T[K] extends (infer U)[] ? NestedConfig<U>[] :
  NestedConfig<T[K]>;
}
```

This is not yet working the way I want. I'm a bit unclear how to create this nested Type.

Comment: Why not something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmUC8UDeBYAKCigGsIQAuKAZ2ACcUE0AaQ4gGwEMAjCdgfiq0GTVkSgA3TuwCuEQVE4IQYgL4BuQoVCQoAOQi0IAE3jJ0WWIlQYAPrjbEoAbTKUa9RmgC6VA0dNrdE0CDSA)?

Comment: But what about if the Config is deeply nested, 2 or more levels deep?

Comment: `any` type disables typescript btw

Comment: I know about `any`, but I was hoping to actually utilize my defined Type. The answer below allowed me to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only want to recursively have constraint for `Config` node type, We can do it with NConfig type alias -

[Code Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmUC8UDeAoKKAawhAC4oBnYAJxQTQBoCoAbAQwCMJWB%20C6nQbNCAN3asArhH5R2CEMwC%20ePKEhQAcvGTossRKgwAfA7rQBtALpRTuKBZLkqtemisVthvUqiq8rBDAUAAenjpG%20viEUEgQ7MCSNBAAjBTRMag8ACZpuCwxxKQUAAZZrLklIjFK1YTl2QBM6QUxTqUNjVWthBzcrBQA5AAWpIOttSyTLHEJSRDN%20YVoNHCSYHkZhQ0UFluFRc4lK2sbAPoN3QdQSlZ1N-cn64v79Sg5LdeE7VDHq88Xd4VK4HSaFMEPVT1eKJZIAZk%20MSeG0RhUokk4yM2PUyQOyqK%20Pz%20pxSZ3RmP%2050u93BNMh13JyJeOLeHyWX2%20xV%20WLJGKZgJyIOuENpE2qkxUQA)

```
type Config = {
  key: string,
  label?: string,
  value?: any,
}

type NConfig = Config | Config[] |  { [key: string]: NConfig } 


let x: NConfig = {
   feature1: {
    field1: {
      key: `field1`,
    },
    field2: {
      key: `field2`,
      label: 'hey'
    },
  },

  feature2: {
    group1: {
      field: [{
        key: `group1_field`,
      }],
    },
    group2: {
      field: {
        key: `group2_field`,
      },
    },
  },

  feature3: {
    group1: {
      subgroup1: {
        field: {
          key: `group1_subgroup1_field`,
        },
      },
      subgroup2: {
        field: {
          key: `group1_subgroup2_field`,
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This did the trick.

It's basically 99% of the solution I was hoping for and is working very well for my needs. What would be even better though is if I can force things so that you only allow a Config on the end of the object tree if you know what I mean?

For example:
`feature1: { key: 'test', group1: { field: { key: 'field' } } }`

Adding a `key` under `feature1` should not actually be allowed. The deeply nested object only allows Config's at the bottom of the nested structure.

Comment: I think even that case is covered by NConfig. Typescript has structural types meaning if two types are assignable to each other then they are interchangeable.
I guess it is not working for `key` in feature is because if you think even { key: 'field' } is the same as `Config` type as other fields are partial `({ key: string, label?: string, value?: any })`, If you name key something else it won't work 

You can check in the code playground why `key` field name is assignable to config and  `lol` is not!

[Code Link](https://tsplay.dev/wjZelw)